# Retrieve Delphi runtime application version and application build information for OSX in fire monkey (FMX)

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey

I try to find an example on how to retrieve the application version and build nr so I can display it in the help box of an OSX application.

Trivial on Windows but on Mac its not.

Hope you can help!

Edward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this code that I have written. Simply call:

```
osxNSBundle.BundleVersion()
```

Here is the code:

```
uses
  Macapi.Foundation,
  Macapi.Helpers;

osxNSBundle = class
private
  class function MainBundle: NSBundle;
public
  class function BundlePath: string;
  class function BundleVersionStr: string;
  class procedure BundleVersion(var aMajor,aMinor,aBuild: integer);
end;

implementation

class function osxNSBundle.MainBundle: NSBundle;
begin
  result := TNSBundle.Wrap(TNSBundle.OCClass.mainBundle);
end;

class function osxNSBundle.BundlePath: string;
begin
  result := NSStrToStr(MainBundle.bundlePath);
end;

class function osxNSBundle.BundleVersionStr: string;
begin
  Result := NSStrToStr(TNSString.Wrap(MainBundle.objectForInfoDictionaryKey(StrToNSStr('CFBundleVersion'))));
end;

class procedure osxNSBundle.BundleVersion(var aMajor,aMinor,aBuild: integer);
var lStrArray: TArray<string>;
i: Integer;
begin
  aMajor := 0; aMinor := 0; aBuild := 0;
  lStrArray := BundleVersionStr.Split(['.']);
  if Length(lStrArray)>=3 then
  begin
    aMajor := lStrArray[0].ToInteger;
    aMinor := lStrArray[1].ToInteger;
    aBuild := lStrArray[2].ToInteger;
  end;
end;
```