# How do I get the version number of the current FMX project in Delphi 12?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

The Delphi 12 IDE allows editing of the FMX module version number in Project | Options | Application | Version Info.

How can I access the build number of my FMX project in code?

Comment: Unfortunately, the RTL/FMX framework does not provide any built-in mechanism to retrieve that info at runtime, so you will have to resort to platform-specific APIs, for instance `GetFileVersionInfo()` on Windows, [`CFBundleVersion` on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65236989/), etc. Or use a 3rd party library/component that handles this for you.

Answer (score 1):

GetVersionString (from FMX.Platform.IFMXApplicationService) returns a string with the version number of the application.

All the details are available here:

- https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Athens/en/FMX.Platform.IFMXApplicationService.AppVersion
- https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Athens/en/FMX.Platform.IFMXApplicationService.GetVersionString

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: IFMXApplicationServie.GetVersionString only returns the major and minor version numbers. I need to access the build number.